# Tilemap rendering with openGL (why the rendering is extremely messed up)

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, tilemap

I'm using SDL & openGL to render a tile-map. The issue is that the tile-map rendering is extremely messed up, and I'm just a bit unsure what I'm doing wrong exactly.

It should just be the first tile being rendered, but I'm getting a blurred mess :S. My rendering code:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
float texscale = 1.0f / (float)tileWidth;
sourceX = sourceX / (float)tileSheetWidth;

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

// Top-left vertex (corner) 
glTexCoord2f( sourceX, sourceY);
glVertex2i(x, y);

// Bottom-left vertex (corner)
glTexCoord2f( sourceX + texscale, sourceY);
glVertex2i( x + tileWidth, y);

// Bottom-right vertex (corner)
glTexCoord2f( sourceX + texscale, texscale + sourceY);
glVertex2i( x + tileWidth, y + tileHeight);

// Top-right vertex (corner)
glTexCoord2f( sourceX, texscale + sourceY);
glVertex2i(x, y + tileHeight);

glEnd();
glLoadIdentity();
```

My initialization code for OpenGL:

```
// Set the OpenGL state after creating the context with SDL_SetVideoMode
glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //Enable 2D rendering
glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height); //Set Up openGL viewport (screen)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, Width, Height, 0, -1, 1); 
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Just in-case, here's my image loading code, I think that perhaps this may be were the problem lies somehow:

```
LoadImage(string filename, bool loadingTileSheet)
{
  SDL_Surface *LoadedImage = NULL;
  GLuint texture;
  Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;
  LoadedImage = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());

  if (loadingTileSheet)
  {
    tileSheetWidth = LoadedImage->w;
    numberOfTiles = (LoadedImage->w / tileWidth) + 1;
  }

  SDL_PixelFormat *pixf = SDL_GetVideoSurface()->format;
  SDL_SetAlpha(LoadedImage, 0, 0);

  if (SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN)    
  {
    rmask = 0xff000000;    
    gmask = 0x00ff0000;   
    bmask = 0x0000ff00;   
    amask = 0x000000ff;
  }
  else 
  {
    rmask = 0x000000ff;    
    gmask = 0x0000ff00;   
    bmask = 0x00ff0000;   
    amask = 0xff000000;
  }

  SDL_Surface *image = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, LoadedImage->w, LoadedImage->h, 32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);
  SDL_BlitSurface(LoadedImage, NULL, image, NULL);

  glGenTextures(1, &texture);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image->w, image->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);

  return texture;
}
```

Comment: Well to update, it seems i'm getting something now, but the rendering is still in-correct.
Image below shows the correct rendering:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/412/unledvg.png/

& the tilesheet (the blue tile was just for testing):
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/6/tilesheet2.png/

I changed GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST and the texscale to:
float texscale = 1.0f / (float)numberOfTiles;

The tile seems somewhat "zoomed in", it seems to be rendering the top section of the tile and not the entire thing.

Comment: Ah, good news i got it working :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code dump + find my problem, doesn't make a good question. I suggest finding code that works via a tutorial or other source, and build off of that code or compare it to yours.

That being said... Test your texture loading code by drawing a quad with the full texture on it (use the texcoords 0 -> 1). If that displays correctly then check your glTexCoord2f calls.

Comment: Doing what you said, the tilesheet loads fine as a full image.
Though, that being said, earlier i tested the code with a simple tilesheet which just had 3 tiles ((96x32) and that rendered fine :S
So that's why i've basically posted all the code just to make sure everything looks fine.

Comment: If the tilesheet loads fine as a full image, then the problem is not in the texture loading code. Check through your glTexCoord2f calls. Set a break point, check their run time values against manually calculated values.

Comment: Thats exactly what i did, stupid me :P. Got it working fine now, thanks for your help/advice though :)

Comment: Sure thing, glad we got it solved. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
float texscale = 1.0f / (float)tileWidth;
;;;
glTexCoord2f( sourceX + texscale, texscale + sourceY);
```

You are computing `texScale` from your x axis but applying it to the y axis too.

Compute the height of a tile in the texture separately from the width of a tile in texture coordinates, as they are different values when your atlas is packed to not have the same number of tiles vertically as horizontally...